# How can i get logs of laravel in docker behind php-fpm?

Tags: php, laravel, docker

During developing we met some problems with getting the real error log of the code.

#### Architecture

nginx -> php-fpm with laravel

#### Problem

can't get the logs of laravel

#### Enviroment

- image php:7.2.8-fpm-alpine3.7
- docker 18.06.1-ce
- laravel 5.5

www.conf

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
clear_env = no
catch_workers_output = yes

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 200
pm.start_servers = 80
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 80
pm.max_requests = 250
request_terminate_timeout = 60

slowlog = /var/log/error.log
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /usr/local/lib/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /usr/local/lib/wsdlcache
;php_value[opcache.file_cache]  = /usr/local/lib/opcache

;monitoring
pm.status_path = /phpfpm_status
ping.path = /phpfpm_ping
ping.response = pong
```

php.ini

```
error_log = "/var/log/error.log"
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
...
```

php-fpm.conf

```
include=/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
[global]
error_log = "/var/log/error.log"
log_level = notice
events.mechanism = epoll
```

i already add full competence to the file /var/log/error.log & access.log
right now,i only get php-fpm log in access.log and error.log

```
/var/log # cat error.log
[20-Mar-2019 06:08:34] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 9
[20-Mar-2019 06:08:34] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
/var/log # cat access.log
172.28.0.5 -  20/Mar/2019:06:34:12 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
172.28.0.5 -  20/Mar/2019:06:34:18 +0000 "POST /index.php" 200
/var/log # pwd
/var/log
```

looking for answers

Comment: Did you enable laravel log ?

Comment: @nhancao yes i already add this into env file APP_LOG=single
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug and i don't think this works,i think the php-fpm will take over all routines.

Comment: Laravel's logs are generated in the application folder under `storage/logs`.

Comment: @apokryfos yes,but when i use php-fpm,it will not out put the log to `storage/logs`,even if i rewrite the monolog with StreamHandler to php://stderr or file,it won't work,i think the php-fpm will ignore laravel life cycle

Comment: It certainly does not do that when using php-fpm outside of docker I don't see why it would do that within docker. however from what you've shared I don't see anything that would cause Laravel to write anything to the log unless you're manually calling `\Log::error` or something like that

Comment: @apokryfos i manually cause exception in my code ,and i alse use `\Log::info,\Log::error,\Log::warning`in my code,doesn't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add stderr/stdout to the logging stack in config/logging.php

This was discussed before here, and Taylor added an example to stderr output (php://stderr) in the config/logging.php shipped with laravel
https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/126

or just change the .env LOG_CHANNEL example quoting original comment: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/126#issuecomment-438548169

> In recent versions (5.6+) the default config/logging.php appears to
>   include a stderr config, so you can just inject a LOG_CHANNEL=stderr
>   environment variable into the container.

This will redirect all error/log based on your logging level to docker logs